# Getting everything from the list(HTML Scraping with python)

Tags: python, html, text, html-lists

I would like to know how can I get everything from the list using a python scraper.
This I want to take http://prntscr.com/dged67
I figured out how to get it but it has some ugly tags I want to get rid of.

```
info = soup.findAll('ul',{'class':'list-unstyled pull-left custom-stats'})
    print info
```

This is the code I'm using. This is what I'm getting http://prntscr.com/dgedzu

Comment: don't use pictures. It's cumbersome to type over text so you would get less help

Answer (score 1):

based on your html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("web.html"), "html.parser")
divs = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'pull-left custom-photo-modal-stats'})
for div in divs:
    for listItem in div.find_all('li'):
       print listItem.getText()
```

Comment: Still prints me what I was getting before I wanna take just the info without html if possible. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="pull-left custom-photo-modal-stats">
                        <h3>Stats</h3>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled pull-left custom-stats">
                            <li><span class="highlight">Eye color:</span> hazel</li>
                            <li><span class="highlight">Hair color:</span> brown</li>
                            <li><span class="highlight">Height:</span> 5'5"</li>
                            <li><span class="highlight">Weight:</span> 110 lbs</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled pull-left custom-stats custom-stats-right">
                            <li><span class="highlight">Breasts:</span> medium</li>
                            <li><span class="highlight">Size:</span> 34/24/37</li>
                            <li><span class="highlight">Shaved:</span> shaved</li>
                            <li><span class="highlight">Ethnicity:</span> Caucasian</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This is the html im trying to get

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dhs43v I figured out how to get all this but now I want to get only <li> objects to have for example Eye Color : hazel \n Hair Color: red